# How do I switch off the integrated Graphics within the UEFI/BIOS of P8B75-m lx?

Tags: motherboard, bios, uefi, integrated-graphics

my Hardware specifics are:

- MOBO: P8B75M-LX
- CPU:  I7-3770
- Name of the integrated Graphics chip: Intel HD graphics 4000

UEFI-BIOS-info: 0803 x64

I read the Manual for the ASUS P8B75M-LX, but there was nothing on how to Switch off the integrated graphic. 
 I searched for a tutorial for on how to deactivate it in the UEFI and it was quiet simple.

But the Problem is, I ve scanned through the UEFI again and again, I even resetted the UEFI with a Jumper but I still could not find in the UEFI any Option where I could have switched off the integrated graphics.

Are the informations I provided sufficient?
Do you know whether this CPU, Motherboard or its UEFI have the Option of switching off?
How do I Switch it off, if it is possible?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you wish for the IG to be entirely disabled? It doesn't cause any drain on your system to be enabled and not active.

Comment: I read on another Forum of so having the same Hardware issues with the same GPU, his GPU could not be detected and so he could not install any Drivers. He was told to Switch off the IG in the UEFI. He did so and his GPU showed up.

Comment: That is not typical behavior on most computers made in the past decade at least. His computer may have had such a limitation, and I've seen those myself, but it was on a much older computer and only happened on a few specific chipsets.

Comment: i really feel like an insane Person, i Switch into the advanced mode of uefi and i go through all menues and submenues which there are again and again and there is nothing about IG...nothing